# Is it possible to send transactional emails with Mailchimp without Mandrill?

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill

If company already subscribed to MailChimp do they need also Mandril to send transactional emails such as app welcome, invites to join or befriend, password recovery etc.

Can one send password recovery or welcome email as one person campaign programmatically using MailChimp alone? Or is it too expensive or too cumbersome?

Comment: Have you tried the new email automation feature by mailchimp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been using Mailchimp for a while and what you are seeking can be **partially** managed with a featured called [automation](http://kb.mailchimp.com/automation/about-automation) within Mailchimp. It allows you to:

- Set up any number of emails as chained emails (so to say) which are triggered individually when *something* happens within the Mailchimp list. For example if someone joins your list, it triggers a welcome message. This automation requires in some cases no code and can be done relatively easy. You can see more automation examples [here](https://us12.admin.mailchimp.com/automations/explore/) (of course you can use their API for more cool stuff).

For password changes notifications, email verifications and such transactional emails you could use Mandrill, but as an add-on within Mailchimp which has a **separate pricing**, where you can start free for the first 2000 emails.

I believe the automation on Mailchimp + a good use of their API to make changes on the list, could easily be put to good use to your advantage (haven't tried this combination yet but will do in the future, let me know if you find out something).

To answer more directly your question, yes, you can achieve a certain degree of automation with the automation part of Mailchimp (which is relatively new), **but** for a more granular control you definitely could use Mandrill as an add-on within Mailchimp.

Comment: so basically I need password reset requested or invite send list (or list segment perhaps), on which I can set a trigger to send email or automation is restricted to welcome abandoned cart and such?

Comment: @Serge you can create a column in your list to signal password reset, another one for invite send list, then segment for each and create an automation workflow for each. Using the API you can update each of these columns to act as triggers.

Comment: There’s also a concern about deliverability: Mailchimp includes headers to tell the receiver’s provider (say Gmail) that the email is bulk (as in newsletter/DEM). Also, email providers know that the servers used by Mailchimp are for bulk email. These signals can result in the email to end up in the Promotions tab or worse in spam. I would expect Mandrill not to include such headers and to use different servers than Mailchimp, and thus to have a better deliverability.

Answer (score 2):

Techically, you *could* create single person campaigns via the [Mailchimp API](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/).
But, Mailchimp has developed it's own anti-spam AI ([Omnivore](https://mailchimp.com/omnivore/)) that kicks in every time the campaign is ready to be sent, which analyzes the campaign and list data.

Since I had Omnivore block some of my campaigns for trivial reasons, I think it would be a matter of time before it finds a pattern in your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view,
MailChimp is not suitable for one-to-one mail triggers, I tried with mailchimp but it's taking to time to implement, so now I'm using Mandril without any conflict & also for bulk triggers mandril is the best choice